# How can I tail a zipped file without reading its entire contents?

Tags: algorithm, compression

I want to emulate the functionality of gzcat | tail -n.

This would be helpful for times when there are huge files (of a few GB's or so).  Can I tail the last few lines of such a file w/o reading it from the beginning? I doubt that this won't be possible since I'd guess for gzip, the encoding would depend on all the previous text.

But still I'd like to hear if anyone has tried doing something similar - maybe investigating over a compression algorithm that could provide such a feature.

Comment: gzip is not textual but binary. So there are no “lines” like in textual data that `tail` could return.

Comment: You might want to check [a similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225751/random-access-to-gzipped-files), [the zlib FAQ](http://zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq28) and [examples/zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c) in the [zlib](http://zlib.net) distribution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, you can't. The [zipping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) works on streams and adapts its internal codings to what the stream contains to achieve its high compression ratio.

Without knowing what the contents of the stream are before a certain point, it's impossible to know how to go about de-compressing from that point on.

Any algorithm which allows you to de-compress arbitrary parts of it will require multiple passes over the data to compress it.

Comment: This is only partly true, depending how the file was constructed.  gzip files can contain multiple streams, with a latter one being entirely independent of former ones.  You can just concatenate gzip files together, and still have a valid gzip file.  I don't know the details, but I presume it's possible to find the location of the last such reset of the stream, supposing that whatever wrote the stream restarts very so often.

Answer (score 9):

BGZF is used to created index gzip compressed BAM files created by Samtools. These are randomly accessible.

http://samtools.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Exactly.  However, it's not just for samtools or for BAMs!  I believe it will work for any line-delimited data.

Comment: BGZF files allow access to random byte offsets inside specially constructed gzips by first limiting the block size, and then for each block storing its length in a BC header (which gzip ignores) to allow random access without decompressing. Tools like BAM store offsets by storing the offset of the block start and also the offset within the block. To get line-oriented indexing you need something like an accompanying bai or tabix file (though these are format and genome specific) to map from your wanted line(s) to offset.

Comment: `bgzip`is the tool to compress using BGZF algorithm that, as it has been already said, is **totally compatible with gzip**. I've developed a tool to tail any bgzip file: `bgztail` (https://github.com/circulosmeos/bgztail), even if it is still growing.

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over what goes into the file in the first place, if it's anything like a ZIP file you could store chunks of predetermined size with filenames in increasing numerical order and then just decompress the last chunk/file.

Comment: This sounds like a good compromise. However, the OP should be aware that this will lower the compression ratio. If testing shows that the ratio change is acceptable, this is a great idea.

Comment: You can actually achieve this by resetting the compression dictionary part-way through a file, thus removing the need to split the file itself into chunks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option, then bzip2 might be a better compression algorithm to use for this purpose.

Bzip2 uses a block compression scheme.  As such, if you take a chunk of the end of your file which you are sure is large enough to contain all of the last chunk, then you can recover it with bzip2recover.

The block size is selectable at the time the file is written.  In fact that's what happens when you set -1 (or --fast) to -9 (or --best) as compression options, which correspond to block sizes of 100k to 900k.  The default is 900k.

The bzip2 command line tools don't give you a nice friendly way to do this with a pipeline, but then given bzip2 is not stream oriented, perhaps that's not surprising.

Answer (score 1):

zindex creates and queries an index on a compressed, line-based text file in a time- and space-efficient way.

https://github.com/mattgodbolt/zindex

Answer (score 1):

Well, **you can** do that if you previously creates an *index* for each file ...

I've developed a command line tool which **creates indexes for gzip files which allow for very quick random access inside them**, and it does this  interleaved with actions (extract, tail, continuous tail, etc):
https://github.com/circulosmeos/gztool

But you can do a tail (`-t`), and the index will be automatically created: if you're gonna do the same in the future it'll be much quicker, and anyway the first time it will take the same time as a `gunzip | tail`:

```
$ gztool -t my_file.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of a fully gzip-compatible pseudo-random access format is [`dictzip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dictzip):

> For compression, the file is divided up into "chunks" of data, each
>   chunk is less than 64kB. [...]
>
> To perform random access on the data, the offset and length of the
>   data are provided to library routines. These routines determine the
>   chunk in which the desired data begins, and decompresses that chunk.
>   Consecutive chunks are decompressed as necessary."