# Read head / tail of gzip file without reading it into memory

Tags: python, gzip, syslog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tail a zipped file without reading its entire contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183001/how-can-i-tail-a-zipped-file-without-reading-its-entire-contents)

I have a 7GB gzip syslog file that extracts to over 25GB. I need to retrieve only the first and last lines of the file without reading the whole file into memory at once.

[`GzipFile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) in Python 2.7 permits use of [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to read the head (iterating via `with` means I don't have to read the whole file):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from gzip import GzipFile
>>> with GzipFile('firewall.4.gz') as file:
...     head = list(islice(file, 1))
>>> head
['Oct  2 07:35:14 192.0.2.1 %ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic TCP translation 
from INSIDE:192.0.2.40/51807 to OUTSIDE:10.18.61.38/2985\n']
```

Python 2.6 version to avoid issues such as `AttributeError: GzipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__'` (since [GzipFile()](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) doesn't support `with` iteration on [GzipFile()](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile))...

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from gzip import GzipFile
>>> class GzipFileHack(GzipFile):
...     def __enter__(self):
...         return self
...     def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
...         self.close()
>>> with GzipFileHack('firewall.4.gz') as file:
...     head = list(islice(file, 1))
```

The problem with this is I have no way to retrieve the tail... [`islice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) doesn't support negative values, and I can't find the way to retrieve the last line without iterating through a 25GB file (which takes way too long).

What is the most efficient way to read the tail of a gzip text file without reading the whole file into memory or iterating over all the lines?  If this can't be done, please explain why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183001/how-can-i-tail-a-zipped-file-without-reading-its-entire-contents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do so. DEFLATE is a stream compression algorithm, which means that there is no way to decompress arbitrary parts of the file without having decompressed everything before it.

Comment: Fair point, so perhaps the best solution to this problem is to grab the tail of the file and archive it as part of my `logrotate` script before I rotate / compress.

Comment: You could also use bzip2 instead, since it's a block compression algorithm. Take the last 5MB or so of the file, run `bzip2recover` on it, and sort though what it leaves behind.

Comment: @mike-pennington: you seem to think this answers your question, but your question as written was not how to do it without scanning through the entire input, but rather how to get the last line without reading the whole file into memory at once.  Is that your question?  If so, then yes it is possible with GzipFile as show in gnibbler's answer.

Answer (score 13):

The deflate format used by gzip compresses in part by finding a matching string somewhere in the immediately preceding 32K of the data and using a reference to the string with an offset and a length.  So at any point the ability to decompress from that point depends on the last 32K, which itself depends on the 32K preceding it, and so on back to the beginning.  Therefore to decompress the data at any point *x* in the stream, you need to have decompressed everything from *0* to *x-1* first.

There are a few ways to mitigate this situation.  First, if you want to frequently access a gzip file randomly, then you would be willing to go through the work of scanning the entire gzip file once and building an index.  The index would have within it the previous 32K saved at each of some number of entry points, where the density of those entry points determines the speed of the random access.  In the [zlib source distribution](http://zlib.net/) you can see an example of this in [examples/zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c).

If you are in control of the generation of the gzip file, you can use the `Z_FULL_FLUSH` flush option to periodically to erase the history of the last 32K at those points to allow random access entry.  You would then save the locations of those points as the index, which would not need the 32K blocks of history at each entry point.  If those points are infrequent enough, there would be a vanishingly small impact on compression.

With just the ability to write gzip output, you can do something similar to `Z_FULL_FLUSH` with a smidge more overhead by simply writing concatenated gzip streams.  `gunzip` will accept and decode gzip streams that are put together with the `cat` command, and will write out a single stream of uncompressed data.  You can build up a large gzip log in this way, remembering somewhere the offsets of the start of each gzip piece.

If you are only interested in the tail, then you can do what you suggest in one of your comments, which is to simply maintain a cache elsewhere of the tail of the large gzip file.

I don't know if you are making the log file or not.  If you are, you may want to look at the [example of appending short log messages to a large gzip file efficiently](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h), found again in the zlib source distribution.

Comment: FWIW: I've developed `gztool` (https://github.com/circulosmeos/gztool) which implements the ideas pointed out by @mark-adler and so allows you to access randomly a gzip file after the index has been created. As the index is also created with any action (tail, extract from # byte, continous tailing, etc) using `gztool` does not increase extraction time the first time and is very convenient if the same file is to be accessed more than once.

Answer (score 6):

gzip file is a stream, so you'll have to read through it to get to the last line

```
from gzip import GzipFile
from collections import deque
dq = deque(maxlen=1)
with GzipFile('firewall.4.gz') as file:
    head = next(file)
    dq.extend(file)
tail = dq[0]
```

Comment: FYI, I tried `collections.deque()` on one of our smaller logfiles (10.2GB)... iterating through the entire file took almost 90 seconds. I need to run this on over a hundred files at a time, so `deque` probably isn't realistic for this application