# search in last line of gzipped file

Tags: unix, grep, command-line-interface, tail

I have a bunch of zipped log files and I am trying to figure out which of the logs ended with an exception.

The only problem I have is that I have no idea how to get the last lines of a bunch zipped file, some sort of bztail would be nice.

Anyone any ideas or knows why this can't work???

Comment: Try `zcat` command, pipe with `grep` for errors.

Comment: But doesnt that command apply to the entire file and finds any exception?

Comment: Yes. You can try `tail` with the pipe. But if you don't want to read the entire content, I don't think you can achieve that, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183001/how-can-i-tail-a-zipped-file-without-reading-its-entire-contents

Comment: I dont mind reading the entire content, but I only want to find exceptions that caused the process to terminate (exceptions on the last log line), the string 'exception' might legitimately appear in other places of the log file, but im not interested in those occurences.

Comment: `zcat <zip filename> | tail -1` doesn't help? Or `zcat <zip filename> | tail -1 | grep exception `?

Comment: ```bzcat <zip filename> | tail -1``` works for one file, but not for an undefined amount of files, since it only returns the last line of the last file, as far as I can tell

Comment: If you have installed `dictzip` and compress your log files with `.dz` extension - I would suggest a working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/the/zip/file/
for i in *.zip
do
     zcat $i | tail -1 | grep exception
     if [ `echo $?` -eq 0 ]
     then
          echo $i
     fi
done
```

The script finds for "exception" in the last line of each and every zip file. If no exception found, nothing to display. If exception found, it is displayed and the filename is displayed below.

Sample output:

```
exception
mail.zip
exception
touch.zip
```

Comment: @Gene Doe, did it work? If so, could you accept my answer?

Comment: agreed, but it also means it doesn't find what I am looking for, because it's definitely there. Well anyways, the problem is outdated by now, but thanks for your input, I really appreciate it.