# How to tail the last nth lines of a file that is located in a compressed tar file

Tags: bash, tar, tail

**Ubuntu 16.04

Bash 4.4.20**

I am wanting to tail the last 30 lines of a SQL file located in a tar.gz file. I noticed that the SQL backups were failing due to a locked file. Instead of me untarring the entire compressed file, I'd like to simply tail the SQL backup and then grep for certain phrases.

This [StackOverflown Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183001/how-can-i-tail-a-zipped-file-without-reading-its-entire-contents) explains that this is not possible with zipped files. Does this also apply to tar files that are created like so:

```
tar czf name.tar.gz foldername
```

If this has been explained in another thread, please delete this thread and I'll keep searching.

Comment: The answers you're linking to don't say what you're interpreting them to say. This is totally possible for zip files.

Comment: ...well, it's right _and_ wrong. It's right in that the decompressor will have to start from the beginning of a given file, so tail will still be doing the work of decompressing the files but throwing away that work until it gets to the last N lines you're asking for. But it's wrong in claiming that you can't write a command that will give you only the last N lines of a file from a zip without creating any temporary files on disk.

Comment: ...that said, zip files are actually _easier_ to `seek()` around in than `tar.gz` files are. With a `.tar.gz` you have to do the `.gz` decompression in order from beginning-to-end. With a zip file it has a footer that tells where each decompressed stream inside the archive lives, so a reader can jump to the specific file it wants to read, without decompressing the ones before it first (as is necessary with a `.tar.gz`).

Comment: ...anyhow, do you have an option to use zip? Given your stated goal, `tar.gz` is the wrong archive format to use if you have a choice. (Then again, if you have total control over the archive, why not just have a file within it that has _only_ the specific content you want to grep?)

Comment: Anyhow: I can give you an answer that will literally do what you're asking for, but it'll be slow, because it'll still be doing the work to read and decompress the data tail is throwing away, which arguably defeats the point of using tail altogether. (Assuming that `grep` is faster than `gunzip` and you have plenty of CPU resources, you may not even get a wall-clock-time benefit over code that didn't use tail at all).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I appreciate the information and willingness to help. I think I'm going to take your advice on using zip for this particular backup. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tar's `-O` option to print content of file then using `| (pipe)`, you can apply basic unix operations, like tail:

```
tar zxvf name.tar.gz <file_to_read> -O | tail
```

Sample command, to read last two lines of a file A1.txt

```
tar zxvf B.tar.gz B/A1.txt -O | tail -2
```

Here B is a directory on which I have ran tar command, it contains many files along with file A1.txt

Comment: It's important to note that `tail` can't `seek()` when given a FIFO, which means that the file still needs to be decompressed and read from the very front (and similarly, `tar` is reading the archive from the far front as well). Insofar as the point of using `tail` at all was performance, it may not be achieved here.